# How to add render to external URL in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to render to external URL using angular 7. 
In angular js we can use as below

`loadExternal(obj){
    var redirect = 'your url';
    $.redirect(obj);
}`

Is there any way to do that in angular7 ?

Comment: you want to show a link on page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let url = 'your url?id=1&name=aakash';
window.open(redirect, "_blank");
```

Comment: I need to pass some data to that url as well how can i do that?

Comment: pass query parameters in url.

Comment: added example above.

Comment: @TharinduDananjaya if it helped, mark it as answer.